# Не работает сортировка в подзапросе

Tags: mysql, sql

```
USE BDPrakt

GO

SELECT *,(
  SELECT product_id, product_name FROM products
  WHERE manufacturer_id = 2 
  ORDER BY product_id DESC ) AS ORDER_BY FROM products
```

Comment: Эта конструкция в принципе может работать только при одном условии, когда в подзапросе возвращается единственная строка, но тогда говорить о сортировки уже не приходится

Answer (score 1):

Сортировка в подзапросе не нужна абсолютно.

В данном случае и подзапрос не нужен:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name
FROM products
WHERE manufacturer_id = 2 
ORDER BY product_id DESC
```